# extracting field values from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a multi-line String, something like this:

```
Welcome to blah blah blah.  Below is the information you requested:
temperature: 12c
windspeed: 30 knotts
humidity: 29%
I hope you have a nice day
```

ok this is a simplified version.  Anyway I want to get the value of a field (e.g. windspeed).  This is one string with new lines (as an aside sometimes strings are just separated by \n and sometimes by \r\n and I am not sure which, but that is an aside).

Anyway, someone wrote this method

```
private String getField(String pdfContent, String field) {
    String temp;
    String value = null;
    int idx = pdfContent.indexOf(field);
    if (idx != -1) {
        temp = pdfContent.substring(idx);
        String line = temp.split(":")[1];
        value = line.split("\n")[0].trim();
        l.info(field + value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Which is fine except say in the instance below, if you want to find value of name:

```
You requested name, age and telephone number.  Below are the results
name: Jenny
age: 22
telephone: 867-5309
```

the method will find the first instance of name.  I guess I could look for a colon after the field but there could be a colon after that as in

```
Following is your request for telephone and name:
telephone: 867-5309
name: Jenny
```

In a normal regexp I would look for "^name:" but I don't think that works in this instance.  Is there a way to find the field at the beginning of a line (in one String)?  Best to look for the colon too, as you could have

```
 name: Merrill Lynch Pierce Fenner Smith
 name_common: Merrill Lynch
```

just looking for name would find the *Merrill Lynch Pierce Fenner Smith* first

Oh and yes, this is Java

Comment: Why wouldn't this work in this case? Have you tried doing it? If yes where is the code and the problem?

Comment: why not split on newline-then-character? Then you'll get an String[] of (fieldName:  fieldValue), then you can split again on ":" to get the values

Comment: how about string.startsWith() method?

Comment: You're right that `String.indexOf(String)` does not recognize or use regexes.  Why not use actual Java regexes, then?

Comment: I have mixed luck with regex.  Sometimes it works.  Sometimes not.  And I still am not sure I can use "^" in this case, or would that just be the beginning of the entrie string?

Comment: You mean do a split("\r\n")?

Comment: You talk about regexes in the question text, and you tag the question [regex].  Your example code doesn't even attempt to use regexes, however, and when I suggest a regex as a natural implementation choice, you seem reluctant to go that direction.  What are you actually asking?

Comment: So, why aren't you searching for `"\n" + name + ":"` and using the content after this string until the next newline/end of file?

Comment: John I am not reluctant.  It just seems I can never figure out the correct syntax.  I can do it find with grep but it seems to be different in Java?

Answer (score 2):

As you have a multi line string i would reckon you to use the Scanner class findinLine() method, this method will read the parts of your string as:

```
scannerobj.findInLine("temperature:");  O/p: 12c
scannerobj.findInLine("windspeed:");    O/p: 30 knotts
scannerobj.findInLine("humidity:");     O/p: 29%
```

Comment: going to look up the documentation for that right now ;-)

Comment: yes please have a look at oracle docs for java they will explain you very efficiently about that method.

Answer (score 0):

you could use: `/^name:\s(.*)$/gm`

with `^` you ensure the line starts with the field.

`:\s` make sure there is a semicolin and a space after the field.

`(.*)$` will read the rest of the line and place it into a group.

Comment: I have tried using ^ before but it seems to work only to the beginning of a string, not of every line.  At least it seemed that way to me.  I can try again.

Comment: did you use the multiline flag? (the /m at the end)